# Apache reverse proxy https

Tags: apache, iframe, https, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have a website which has an iframe and inside that it loads content from reverse proxy. The setup work perfectly in case of http.

But problem comes when https is loaded in reverse proxy.

inside the iframe content is loaded as http protocol (through browser console I checked location object) which is not secure. I want to tell proxy if the backend content is https then load https inside iframe though outer page is http.

Can I do this?

Below is how I programmed /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        ServerName localhost
        SSLProxyEngine On
        RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
```

Comment: I think it's not problem of the proxy. Proxy is serve for your frame. The main site (which load frame) will decide when it will load http or https to the frame.
Im not sure that I understand your question, but let check `mod_proxy_html`, it could help.

Comment: Thanks @JerryPham . The problem is when I proxy https content it still serves as http inside iframe. I want to change it depending on backend.

Comment: This has to be done using The Header:  `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1`  which will force http to be upgraded to https -- if thats your question... can you clarify  a  little bit by including  the code thats causing the problem as well as the expected behavior and the actual behavior in the form of code?

Comment: Learn more about how to include all the necessary information in your questions here: [ask]

Comment: Also port 443 is the typical https port -- port 80  is for plaintext http -- and you dont have SSLEngine